# Implementing Accelerometer in Android App

Tags: android, apk, accelerometer, sensors

I have a very simple MainActivity.smali file that i want to ultimately invoke MainService.smali. That much is not the problem. The problem arises when i try to write in code to have the accelerometer sensor event invoke MainService.smali.

I'm using a standard text editor and apktool to decompile and build my packages. The package fails to build from errors such as:

```
test/smali/com/home/launch/MainActivity.smali[5,0] missing EOF at 'public'
Could not smali file: com/home/launch/MainActivity.smali
```

The Main question being how can i correcly implement this accelerometer SensorEvent code?

I would really appreciate someone helping me understand what i'm doing wrong as i'm trying to learn this thank you in advance.

This is the working code i use to invoke MainService.smali:

```
.class public Lcom/home/launch/MainActivity;
.super Landroid/app/Activity;


# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 0

    invoke-direct {p0}, Landroid/app/Activity;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method


# virtual methods
.method protected onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    .locals 0

    invoke-super {p0, p1}, Landroid/app/Activity;->onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V

    invoke-static {p0}, Lcom/home/launch/MainService;->startService(Landroid/content/Context;)V

    invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/home/launch/MainActivity;->finish()V

    return-void
.end method
```

This is what the code looks like when i attempt to implement the SensorEvent:

```
.class public Lcom/home/launch/MainActivity;
.super Landroid/app/Activity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener{

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    sensor accelerometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(MainActivity.this, acceleeometer, 
SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    .method public constructor <init>()V
        .locals 0

        invoke-direct {p0}, Landroid/app/Activity;-><init>()V

        return-void
    .end method


    .method protected onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
        1.locals 0

        invoke-super {p0, p1}, Landroid/app/Activity;->onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V

        invoke-static {p0}, Lcom/home/launch/MainService;->startService(Landroid/content/Context;)V

        invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/home/launch/MainActivity;->finish()V

        return-void
    .end method

}

}
```

Comment: @lenik How to correctly implement the code and or eliminate the errors.

Comment: start from existing accelerometer samples, not from reverse engineered code?